# Is it safe to delete metric events file in google compute engine vm

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-container-optimized-os

So, I found a file called `uma-events` under metrics folder in a google compute engine vm(built using Container Optimized OS) which is taking about 5gb space. I cannot extend the partition in the current condition and am running low on disk space. Also, the file mentioned above is owned by `chronos`(Maybe it is a default user/group?) So, would it be safe to delete the file?

full path of the file is - `/mnt/stateful_partition/var/lib/metrics/uma-events`

I went through several documentations but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

The root file system is mounted as read-only to protect system integrity. However, home directories and **/mnt/stateful_partition** are persistent and writable.

You can remove it as a temporary solution or you can resize it.

**To resolve your issue, do the following:**

1. [Create a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots) of the disk : Make sure that the changes you will do on your instance won't affect your system performance. So that you can easily revert it back to your previous instance state.
2. Delete files that you don't need on the disk to free up space(Your safe to be removed metrics folder), to learn more about these directories, See [Disks and file system](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/disks-and-filesystem) overview.
3. If your disk requires more space after this, [resize the disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-disk-full-resize#filesystem). (If  your VM might become inaccessible if your boot disk is full, to troubleshoot full disk or resize disk refer to this link [Troubleshooting full disks and disk resizing.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-disk-full-resize)